# Need Help in Restricting Player Movement to Only 2 Axis,

Tags: unity, side-scroller

I am creating a 2.5D Side Scrolling type Game. For the most part I am using a 3rd Person Character controller. The Major Problem that I am facing is how I can limit the motion of my Player Character to Just 2 Axis. I want to make a Fully Fledged Game so Climbing Ropes and Jumping Rocks etc everything will be there. I am not quite experienced with Unity. Although I have created few 2D. For the 3D World it’s Just a different Universe.
There are Zillions of things out there on internet and I have researched allot and read, understood and done so many things to get my task done. But I am unable to achieve what I am looking for.
I want my character controller to Use Mechanim, It is creating issues for me because almost All of the tutorials that I am focusing are Legacy Animation Oriented.
Please Help me so I may proceed.
I am not asking for spoon feeding and Kindly excuse me if I am doing wrong by posting.

Comment: The rigid body component has options to freeze axis'. This will prevent physics from affecting those axis', but will not work for direct transform manipulation.

Comment: Well, I have tried that but it behaves weird.
I don't know what I am doing wrong.
well thanks for answering.